sparql query vs snap sparql query in protege
I am trying to understand the difference between SPARQL Query and Snap SPARQL Query tabs on Protege Desktop version.
I want retrieve all the direct subclasses of a certain class, say class A, and not the inferenced ones, for example, if C and D are subclasses of B, and B is a subclass of A, then just return B and not B, C and D. I am writing a SPARQL query for the same.
1 namespace: <ontology IRI>
2 SELECT ?directSub 
3 WHERE { ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A .
4         FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?otherSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A. 
5                             ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSub .
6                             FILTER (?otherSub != ?directSub)
7        }
8 }

The above query is from this stack overflow post.
When I try to run this on SPARQL Query tab on Protege, it shows error Expected one of Any BuiltIn( on line 4, on NOT specifically. So to go step by step, I tried to execute the simple query below on Snap SPARQL Query tab again,
1 namespace: <ontology IRI>
2 SELECT ?directSub 
3 WHERE { ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A .
4 }

It returned all the classes B, C and D as result.
So I ran the same query on SPARQL query tab on Protege,
1 namespace: <ontology IRI>
2 SELECT ?directSub 
3 WHERE { ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A .
4 }

and it only returns the direct subclasses of A, which is B.
So, here are my following questions:

What is the difference between SPARQL Query and Snap SPARQL Query tabs on Protege?
What is the reason for getting two different outputs in these tabs though they run the same SPARQL query?
Why does "SPARQL Query" tab display an error on "FILTER NOT EXISTS"?

Note: I am guessing SPARQL query tab runs without reasoner, and Snap SPARQL Query tab runs only with reasoner?!


Snap SPARQL does support some level of inference. 2. Apparently I'm confused by the results, for the Snap SPARQL query tab it should return all subclasses of :A, also the inferred - that should not happen via the default SPARQL query tab. Are you sure you did not mix up the results reported here? 3. it works on a very old version of RDF4J as query engine (dubbed "Sesame") which at the time did not support all SPARQL 1.1 features, and  FILTER NOT EXISTS would be one of it


you can use the old version to check for absence of data by using OPTIONAL { ... } in combination with FILTER(!BOUND(...)) -

thanks for pointing out the error while mentioning the query tabs, I made the edits now. I will try out the keywords you suggested in my queries and post the results.

it should be something like (untested) SELECT ?directSub  WHERE {  ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A . OPTIONAL { ?otherSub rdfs:subClassOf namespace:A .  ?directSub rdfs:subClassOf ?otherSub .   FILTER (?otherSub != ?directSub) } FILTER(!BOUND(?otherSub)) }
